# displaying results of union in different columns - mysql

Tags: mysql

the query

```
select 
   min(temperature) as minTemp, 
   max(temperature) as maxTemp from test 
union  
( 
   select 
      temperature as Temp , 
      datetime as Date 
   from test 
      order by datetime desc 
   limit 1
)
```

returns the result:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| minTemp | maxTemp             |
+---------+---------------------+
|   24.11 | 26.739999771118164  |
|   25.93 | 2017-05-14 15:11:09 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

How can i display the results in seperate columns like :

```
+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+
| minTemp | maxTemp             |   Temp   |Date                  |
+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+
|   24.11 | 26.739999771118164  | 25.93    | 2017-05-14 15:11:09  |
|         |                     |          |                      |
+---------+---------------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Union combines results of more than one sets. Why do u need union if want to achieve this?. Just use multiple selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case `CROSS JOIN` is your friend. You could do it like this:

```
select 
   min(temperature) as minTemp, 
   max(temperature) as maxTemp,
   t.Temp,
   t.Date
from 
    test 
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        select 
          t1.temperature as Temp , 
          t1.datetime as Date 
       from 
          test as t1 
       order by 
          t1.datetime desc 
       limit 1
    ) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this, is to add dummy columns, then use grouping to merge them together.  e.g.

```
Select max(minTemp),max(maxTemp),max(Temp),max(Date) from (
   select 
      min(temperature) as minTemp, 
      max(temperature) as maxTemp from test , null as Temp, Null as Date
   union  
   ( 
      select null as minTemp, null as maxtemp,
         temperature as Temp , 
         datetime as Date 
      from test 
         order by datetime desc 
      limit 1
   )
)
```

This only works in your example because you will always have exactly one row in each part of the query, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Union adds the result ROWS of two tables as one resultset. Join adds COLUMNS from two or more tables as one row. So join would probably be a better choice in this scenario.

HOWEVER for this to work you need to have something to join on, eg an id or exact date or similar. Since I dont know if you have this here is a sample SQL:

```
select 
min(test1.temperature) as minTemp, 
max(test1.temperature) as maxTemp, 
test2.temperature as Temp, 
test2.datetime as Date 
from test test1 join test test2 
on _something_that_you_can_join_on_ 
order by datetime desc limit 1
```

test1 and test2 are aliases for the two tables that we join together.

Do you have any column you could join on?